# change drop down width with ajax or jquery

Tags: css, ajax, width, html-select

I have a country drop down that triggers an ajax call to fetch child states on selection.

This is the state drop down html:

```
<div id="statediv"  ><select name="state" style="width:200px;" id="stateDrop">
```

with this function: (it works)

```
  function getState(countryId) {  



var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
var req = getXMLHTTP();

if (req) {

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
      // only if "OK"
      if (req.status == 200) {   

        document.getElementById(\'statediv\').innerHTML=req.responseText;   




      } else {
        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
      }
    }       
  }     
  req.open("GET", strURL, true);
  req.send(null);
}
```

}

when the page loads the drop down is the correct width, but when a country is selected and the states load, the state drop down changes/loses the width setting and defaults to the biggest word in the drop down. Ive tried giving the state dropdpwn an id and changing it with jquery but its not working - any ideas?

tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loosing the width setting because you're replacing the contents of `statediv`, and the select and the width setting are inside `statediv`. If you set the width in a CSS block outside of `statediv` then the width should be preserved.

```
<style>
    #statediv select {
        width:200px;
    }
</style>

<div id="statediv">
    <select name="state" id="stateDrop">
    ...
```

Comment: yikes thats embarrassing. lol. I was trying to do it with ajax/jq- hmmm thanks chaps! I had a style on the drop down only but that was obviously not enough..

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your CSS file:

```
#statediv select {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Your script is basically replacing the state drop down, that's why it changes its width.